# Setting the state with hooks after the first render and then allowing the user to change it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following component, where I tried to set the state values (using hooks) after the data is loaded. The problem is that, the code does not let me change these initial values when I try to type in the text boxes.

I know each time I type, useEffect is called, which reset the typed values. I do no understand why `props.reviewRounds[props.reviewRoundId] != null` condition does not work, which checks if data is already loaded or not (in redux store). Any ideas?

```
const [st_CourseTitle, set_CourseTitle] = useState('');
const [st_AssignmentTitle, set_AssignmentTitle] = useState('');
const [st_ReviewRound, set_ReviewRound] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    if (props.loading != true)
        props.fetchReviewRoundCardDataForInstructor(reviewRoundId);

    if (props.reviewRounds[props.reviewRoundId] != null) {
        set_AssignmentTitle(props.reviewRounds[props.reviewRoundId].assignmentTitle);
        set_CourseTitle(activeCourseService.currentCourseValue.title);
        set_ReviewRound('review-round-' + props.reviewRounds[props.reviewRoundId].round);
    }

}, [props.reviewRounds, props.reviewRoundId])
```

Related part of the `return` statement:

```
 <input type="text"
     className="small"
     value={st_CourseTitle}
     onChange={(event) => { set_CourseTitle(event.target.value) }}
 />
 <span className="text-muted"> / </span>
 <input type="text"
     className="small"
     value={st_AssignmentTitle}
     onChange={(event) => { set_AssignmentTitle(event.target.value) }}
 />
 <span className="text-muted"> / </span>
 <input
     type="text"
     className="small"
     value={st_ReviewRound}
     onChange={(event) => { set_ReviewRound(event.target.value) }}
 />
```

Comment: Can you add some `console.log` calls to see what the data is during each call to `useEffect`? It's difficult to debug further from what you've pasted. It looks okay.